# add constraint to programmatically created button

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

Hello I have showing `UIButton` in `tableView` footer programmatically. The problem is it is not showing correctly in smaller phones like 5s. The button title is going right on the smaller screens. 
[image]

You can see in the image that button title is not in the center

This is how I am showing the button

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height))


        nextButton   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        nextButton!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 414, 65)

        nextButton!.setTitle("NEXT", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        nextButton!.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
       nextButton!.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Variables.MONTESERRAT_REGULAR, size: 20.0)



          nextButton!.backgroundColor = UIColor().blueColor()       //top
          nextButton!.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,10.0, 10.0, 0.0)

          nextButton!.addTarget(self, action: "nextButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        footerView.addSubview(nextButton!)


        return footerView
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use auto layout(VFL) instead of setting some random static frame,

```
let containerView = UIView()
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()


let buttonNext = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
buttonNext.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
buttonNext.setTitle("NEXT", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
//buttonNext.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

containerView.addSubview(buttonNext)

self.view.addSubview(containerView)

var verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[containerView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["containerView": containerView])

var horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[containerView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["containerView": containerView])

self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraint)
self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraint)


verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[buttonNext]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["buttonNext": buttonNext])

horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[buttonNext]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["buttonNext": buttonNext])

self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraint)
self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraint)
```

You can set the title alignment if you want any specific.

Hope this helps you.

**Edit/Update:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?

    let footerView = UIView()
    footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 50)
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let buttonNext = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    buttonNext.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 50)
    buttonNext.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonNext.setTitle("NEXT", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonNext.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    footerView.addSubview(buttonNext)

    footerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    return footerView

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```

Comment: could you please edit my code so I can replace your code with mine. I am sorry I am new to ios.

Comment: Okay only small little problem left. the button is fixed on small screens but on 6sPlus it the button is slightly above from bottom so it shows white area

Comment: Provide screenshot for more clarity. Try playing with the button height as a workaround.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045420/set-button-on-bottom-of-static-tableview/36049166#36049166