# set button on bottom of static tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tablefooterview

hello I want to set the programmatically created button at bottom of static `tableView`. The problem I am having is the botton stays at the bottom on smaller phones(5s) which is completely fine. But on 6s Plus it shows white area underneath the button. Meaning the button is slightly above from the ground or above from edge of the bottom. [image]

This is how I am setting the button

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?

    let footerView = UIView()
    footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 50)
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let buttonNext = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    buttonNext.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 50)
    buttonNext.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonNext.setTitle("NEXT", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonNext.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    footerView.addSubview(buttonNext)

    footerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    return footerView

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a footer at the bottom of the table, rather than at the end of the section. In this case you should use the table's `tableFooterView` property. You could do this with the following code in `viewDidLoad` (or elsewhere):

```
let footerView = UIView()
footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 50)
footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

let buttonNext = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
buttonNext.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 50)
buttonNext.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
buttonNext.setTitle("NEXT", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
buttonNext.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

Comment: the footerview comes below the cell, I need to set always at the bottom end. How can I achieve this ?